# SharePoint Workflow Waiting on Date update

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow that waits until a date that is provided in a list and I change that date in the list does the workflow update?

For example, if I add an item to the list and the date field for that item is set to 6/27 and then two days later I change the date in the item to 6/29 is the workflow waiting on the first or second date. The workflow is set to start once an item is added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow will wait for the initial date. In your case wait until 6/27.

Once the workflow executes the pause statement it won`t consider the change on that date column.